# Persist collection in object with MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, collections, persistence, mybatis

I have POJO classes:

```
class Ticket {
    private int id;
    private double cost;
    private Date time;
    private List<Place> places;

    // Getters and setters here
}

class Place {
    private int row;
    private int place;

    // Getters and setters here
}
```

Then I create one ticket and some places:

```
Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
ticket.setCost(58.7);
ticket.setTime(new Date());

Place place1 = new Place();
place1.setRow(1);
place1.setPlace(2);
ticket.addPlace(place1);

Place place2 = new Place();
place2.setRow(3);
place2.setPlace(4);
ticket.addPlace(place2);
```

And now I want to save it to DB:

```
session.insert("insertTicket", ticket);
session.commit();
```

In MapperConfig.xml I write this lines:

```
<insert id="insertTicket" parameterType="Ticket">
    INSERT INTO tickets (cost, time) VALUES (#{cost}, #{time})
</insert>
```

How I can save **List places** in automatic mode?
Does MyBatis can save it for me?
Or I need to iterate manually with **foreach** and insert every **Place** by hand?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even though MyBatis is able to support the reverse direction (i.e. filling the list during a query with a nested select or from a join), there is no automatic mode that inserts the containing list into the database.

According to this [Google Groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/mybatis-user/browse_thread/thread/3a262fbade08c957/67f2678c9a745bbf) you have to insert the list elements manually.

Comment: Hm. Not good... I think MyBatis smarter. Is exist ORM for Java that can do this operation for me?

Comment: MyBatis actually _is_ smart. But it is not intended to be a ORM. It's only meant as a thin wrapper around JDBC. If this functionality is a requirement then you can look for a ORM like Hibernate http://www.hibernate.org/ or EclipseLink http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/ .