# How to handle one to many insert stored procedure?

Tags: apache-camel, mybatis

Recently, I come across a complex issue about Camel MyBatis one to many insert.
My case is that I try to insert a bunch of items into two SQLServer tables by stored procedure.
The item data structure is one to many, that means one item include another list of other items, like below:

```
Class MainItem{
  String id;
  String name;
  ....
  List<SubItem> subItems;
}

Class SubItem {
  String error;
  String desc;
  String author;
  .....
}
```

I need to insert MainItems into one table, and insert SubItems into another table.
When inserting SubItems, the values from MainItem should be passed to stored procedure.
The insert stored procedures are total separated.

I don't know if the MyBatis could handle this complicate case.
Does the MyBatis support nested mapper file? Like a mapper file can include another mapper file. It it does so. I think that doing insert SubItems when doing insert MainItems will be achieved. 
Or somebody can offer some solution?
Any suggestion and hint will be appreciate.

Comment: Afaik, nested inserts are not supported ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649089/mybatis-insert-with-complex-object ). You will probably have to call the inserts manually from your code.

Comment: Thanks. I will implement Mybatis in Camel. So I need to insert one by one. Do the Mybatis support nested select. Something likes in one select call another select by id in mapper xml file?

Comment: Yes, nested selects are supported, as well as lazy loading with them. See association and collection in the documentation: http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#select