# MyBatis Complex Insert

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm trying to make an insert statement that will allow me to insert into multiple tables in one block but haven't had any success. Here is an example:

## Java objects:

```
public class  Parent {
    String parentId;
    List<Child> children;
    ...getters and setters...
}

public class Child {
    String childId;
    List<Toy> toys;
    ...getters and setters...
}

public class Toy {
    String toyId;
    String color;
    ...getters and setters...
}
```

## MySQL Tables

```
create table TOY (TOY_ID varchar(10), COLOR varchar(10), CHILD_ID varchar(10),
  primary key(TOY_ID), foreign key (CHILD_ID) references CHILD(CHILD_ID));

create table CHILD (CHILD_ID varchar(10), PARENT_ID varchar(10),
  primary key(CHILD_ID), foreign key (PARENT_ID) references PARENT(PARENT_ID));

create table PARENT (PARENT_ID varchar(10), primary key(PARENT_ID));
```

## mapper.xml

```
<resultMap id="ToyResult" type="Toy">
    <id property="toyId" column="TOY_ID"/>
    <result property="color" column="COLOR"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="ChildResult" type="Child">
    <id property="childId" column="CHILD_ID"/>
    <collection property="toys" ofType="Toy" resultMap="ToyResult"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="ParentResult" type="Parent">
    <id property="parentId" column="PARENT_ID"/>
    <collection property="children" ofType="Child" resultMap="childResult"/>
</resultMap>
```

**I want to know if it is possible to do an insert mapping like the following:**

```
<insert id="insertParentData" parameterType="Parent">
    insert into PARENT(PARENT_ID) values(#{parentId});

    insert into CHILD(CHILD_ID, PARENT_ID) values
      <foreach collection="children" item="childItem" index="index0" separator=",">
        (#{childItem.childId}, #{parentId})
      </foreach>;

    insert into TOY(TOY_ID, COLOR, CHILD_ID) values
      <foreach collection="children" item="childItem" index="index0" separator=",">
          <foreach collection="childItem.toys" item="toyItem" index="index1" separator=",">
            (#{toyItem.toyId}, #{toyItem.color}, #{childItem.childId})
        </foreach>
      </foreach>
</insert>
```

I've been getting an error message saying there is an error in my SQL syntax. It points out the `insert into CHILD` line.

If this insertion method isn't possible, how would you suggest I map the insert statements? I could create ParentMapper, ChildMapper, and ToyMapper xml files and in my Parent Data Access Object I would have three insert calls, each one inserting to a different table using a different mapper.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649089/mybatis-insert-with-complex-object
Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287544/persist-collection-in-object-with-mybatis

Comment: @GabrielMolina thank you, I hadn't seen that question before. I decided to have separate inserts and called each one separately.

Comment: Individual inserts is the way to go.  Just wrap all inserts in a transaction so they all roll back if one fails.

Answer (score 0):

There must be an  element for each query. Maybe you can make a "insertParent" java method that, after the parent insert, calls a "insertChildren" method for his children, that recursively calls a "insertToys" method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by separating the big insert into three separate inserts and calling them in my DAO.

Comment: @Geoorge, can you share the complete answer here